# Opening a docx document in Word from a browser

Tags: html, browser, ms-word, glassfish

i have a primefaces webapp running on a glassfish server, which has a specific section used to manage word documents.
In this section the user can see his documents and add information relevant to the system to it, and also replace a document.
What i'd like to do is make a button that would open ms word on the user computer, downloading a given document, without needing to:

- make him download the docx
- make him open it manually
- make him unlock the document for editing (since it was downloaded from the internet it will be locked).

Is there a way I can do that directly? This must be compatible with chrome, firefox and IE (at least the latest versions)

Comment: at most you can SUGGEST that word be used, by outputting the appropriate mime header. but there is no way to reliably FORCE word to open, especially if the user's mapped .docx to some other app (e.g. openoffice, or even something completely different, like a hex editor).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already suggest the use of word using the MIME type. 
What i'm looking toward is opening the document in word for the user automatically, given that he must have word installed in order to use the webapp (the documents aforementioned are actually produced only with a word plugin, so...) Should i write a browser extension?